# Realizar un split por comas teniendo en cuenta si hay comillas

Tags: java, split

Tengo las siguientes líneas en java:

```
1234,"Calle Jaime III, 34", 67,3,U
1235,Avenida Los Algodones, 12,1,L
1236,"Calle Principal""31234", 46,3,H
1237,"Calle Alfonso X,22", 65,2,J
```

Me gustaría realizar un **Split** por el carácter

> ,

pero como se ve en el ejemplo la dirección tiene comillas por lo que cuando se tiene una coma dentro de un campo con comillas el Split se realiza mal.

Intento que se obtenga lo siguiente:

```
1234    Calle Jaime III 34       67     3     U
1235    Avenida Los Algodones    12     1     L
1236    Calle Principal 31234    46     3     H
1237    Calle Alfonso X 22       65     2     J
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar una librería de lectura de CSV.

Comment: Podrías realizar un _replaceall_  antes de realizar el _split_

Comment: @Dev.Joel con replaceall, tendría el mismo problema ya que al quitar las comillas se separarían los campos por las comas y por lo tanto en el caso 1 se separaría Calle Jaime III y por otro lado 34.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He encontrado una solución a tu problema en SO en inglés en la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757107/3683321)

en la que se utiliza la siguiente expresión regular, en la que hace el split en la coma sólo si esa coma tiene cero, o un número par de comillas por delante

```
,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

A continuación te pongo un pequeño código java para probar dicha expresión

```
String line = "1234,\"Calle Jaime III, 34\", 67,3,U";
String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
for(String t : tokens) {
    System.out.println("> "+t);
}
```

Mostrando por pantalla lo siguiente:

> 1234
>
> "Calle Jaime III, 34"
>
> 67
>
> 3
>
> U

Por otra parte he hecho la prueba de la expresión regular con los datos que has puesto en una página llamada https://regex101.com y funciona correctamente como puedes observar en la siguiente [página](https://regex101.com/r/CvSptX/1)

Si además quieres quitar las comillas y la coma puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
String line = "1234,\"Calle Jaime III, 34\", 67,3,U";
String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
for(String t : tokens) {
    t = t.replace(",","");
    t = t.replace("\"", "");
    System.out.println("> "+t);
}
```

para que quede exactamente como los datos que quieres obtener.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado

Answer (score 1):

Si los patrones que tenes son exactamente esos, podes hacer en cada registro
replaceAll(" , ", " ") con esto removerías solamente la coma que "molesta" para el split o StringTokenizer del primer caso del ejemplo, ya que las demás comas no están separadas por espacios.
Luego haces el split o StringTokenizer en forma normal y finalmente un nuevo replaceAll("\"", "") para quitar todas la comillas.
Repitiendo este procedimiento en cada registro debería dejarlo como el resultado final esperado.
Si tenes mas patrones poné todos los ejemplos y seguimos pensando....

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. He estado mirando y he editado la pregunta con los patrones exactos. No siempre hay comas con espacios por lo que tu solución propuesta no me encajaría.